# Create a view combining two tables ms sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to create a view combining two tables: Task and Status

What I did was:

```sql
CREATE VIEW todolist
select     tasks.taskname, 
           tasks.description 
FROM  status 
INNER JOIN tasks 
ON  status.statusid = tasks.statusid 
WHERE ( status.statusid = 1)
```

But they told me that the above example is wrong
and the right answer is:

```sql
CREATE todolist AS VIEW SELECT tasks.taskname, 
           tasks.description 
FROM  status 
INNER JOIN tasks 
ON  status.statusid = tasks.statusid 
WHERE ( status.statusid = 1)
```

Which don't make sense since the last example have wrong syntax to create the view, I mean the first line:

```sql
CREATE todolist AS VIEW SELECT tasks.taskname,
```

Which is the right answer?

Comment: You're missing a name for your View in the first statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
CREATE VIEW todolist 
AS 
SELECT tasks.taskname, tasks.description 
FROM  status 
INNER JOIN tasks 
ON  status.statusid = tasks.statusid 
WHERE ( status.statusid = 1)
```

The full syntax is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend using table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read:

```
CREATE VIEW todolist AS
    SELECT t.taskname, t.description 
    FROM status s INNER JOIN
         tasks t
         ON s.statusid = t.statusid 
    WHERE s.statusid = 1;
```

(Your version missed the `AS`.)  More importantly, the `JOIN` is not needed.  You are only using columns from the `tasks` and the `WHERE` is on the `JOIN` column.

So, the better way to write this is:

```
CREATE VIEW todolist AS
    SELECT t.taskname, t.description 
    FROM tasks t
    WHERE t.statusid = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that `statusid` is unique in `status`, but that seems like a very reasonable assumption.

If you are learning SQL, you should be learning how to write queries correctly and concisely.